# How to dynamically generate an html string using a pandas DataFrame in Python 3?

Tags: python, html, string, pandas, format

I have the following dataframe column:

```
print(df['keyword'])

                   keyword
1    ['aloe gel', 'how to plant aloe']
2    ['avocado oil hair', 'best avocado oil']
3    ['2019 hairstyles']
4    ['peel off mask', 'charcoal face mask', 'charcoal powder']
5    ['nyx eyebrow pencil', 'eyebrow waxing']
6    ['matcha green']
7    ['hair growth oil']
8    ['organic coconut milk', 'organic milk', 'organic compounds']
9    ['apple vinegar cider']
```

I would like to pass each python string (so aloe gel, how to plant aloe, etc...) in one long HTML string.

I expect the output to look something like this in HTML:

```
 <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>
        <span style="color: rgb(40, 50, 78);">aloe gel.</span>
        <span style="color: rgb(184, 49, 47);">how to plant aloe.</span> 
        <span style="color: rgb(40, 50, 78);">avocado oil hair.</span></strong>
    </p>
```

and thus like this as a result:

**aloe gel. how to plant aloe. avocado oil hair.**

I believe I would need to use a for loop to add each keyword to the HTML string as well as a for loop to iterate over the colors.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  I suspect you are getting down votes because you didn't show your code.

Comment: Hi I am pretty new to Stack, I did not know I have to show my full code. I will remember this for the future :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do what you are looking for. If not, could you clarify?

```
html = '<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>'

colors = ['40, 50, 78', '184, 49, 47']
colorIdx = 0
#iterate through rows of dataframe
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    #iterate through values in keyword column
    for strVal in row['keyword']:
        #add the span to the html string
        html += '<span style="color: rgb({});">{}</span>'.format(colors[colorIdx], strVal)
        #switch the colorIdx to switch back and forth between colors
        colorIdx = 0 if colorIdx > 1 else 1


html += '</strong></p>'
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if my post was not clear, I will change that for future questions. Thank you very much!